# Spatial joins in OGR SQL

Tags: open-source-gis, sql, ogr

I have seen that OGR supports it's own form of SQL, I was wondering if it's possible to do spatial joins.

Something like select all objects where one intersects the other.  I did have a look around but couldn't really see anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OGR SQL is only for standard attribute queries, and not for spatial queries.

[Link](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html)

The only geometry related queries that can be run are to query by area using the keyword OGR_GEOM_AREA

```
SELECT * FROM nation WHERE OGR_GEOM_AREA > 10000000'
```

If you run the OGR SQL against a datasource that is a database then the SQL query is executed using the database's own SQL implementation.

You can also pass in spatial queries directly to a geodatabase using the [ExecuteSQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510080916/http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRDataSource.html#a6acc228db6513784a56ce12334a8c33) command on a [OGRDataSource](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510080916/http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRDataSource.html). This method also allows a bonding box to be passed in as a filter.

To do queries such as intersections with OGR you'd need to use the [OGRGeometryClass](https://gdal.org/api/ogrgeometry_cpp.html). Personally I find it easier to use the opensource [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/shapely/) library for these types of query, or use the spatial queries in the underlying geodatabase (SQL Server, Oracle, PostGIS etc.)

Comment: ogr2ogr has a spatial query option, -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax. The input extent can only be a rectangle.

Comment: @klewis - I've updated the answer to mention the use of ExecuteSQL which could be used to run spatial queries directly on a DBMS or further filter records by bounding box.

Comment: What about http://www.spatialthoughts.com/blog/gis/ogr-spatial-join/